# How to inspect nodejs stack & code segment memory usage

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, v8

I am experiencing a 'slow' memory increase in my node process which runs for longer periods of time (~1GB in over 2 months), however the heap stays constant (which implies that my code/stack is growing). I also tried to manually call the garbage collector but memory usage remains the same.

How can I investigate this further ? I want to confirm my theory and figure out why is my code segment / stack part growing.

I am using node v8 LTS (I know this is EOL from this year, I just need to know if there's a way to figure this out)

Answer (score 2):

(V8 developer here.)

Code generated by V8 is on the heap, so if the heap isn't growing, that means that code isn't growing either.

The stack size is limited by the operating system, usually to 1-8 MB. Since operating systems simply kill processes that run into the stack limit, V8 imposes an even lower limit (a little less than a megabyte, I think it's 984KB currently) onto itself, and will throw a `RangeError` if that's ever exceeded. So a growing stack can't be your problem either.

Since you say that the heap memory reported by Node/V8 remains constant, that also means that most "how to debug memory leaks in Node" tutorials don't apply to your situation; and that probably also means that the leak is not in your (JavaScript) code.

That leaves C++ "heap memory" (which is very different from V8's managed "heap"!) as the most likely culprit. Node itself as well as native extensions can freely allocate memory that they manage themselves. Maybe something doesn't get cleaned up properly there. That could simply be an upstream bug; or it could be that something in your code is accidentally holding on to some embedder memory.

What I would try first is to update Node and any native extensions you have installed. Maybe the leak has already been found and fixed.

If that doesn't help, then you could try to investigate where the memory is going. For instance, you could compile everything from source with LSan enabled, and see if that reports anything. It would probably be helpful to construct a stress-test, e.g. a fake client that floods (a test instance of) your server with real-looking requests, to try to trigger inspectable instances of the leak in seconds or minutes rather than months. Crafting such a fake client might also help narrow down where things go wrong (e.g.: maybe you'll notice that one type of request does not trigger the leak but another type of request does).